# Compute the standard matrix of P to V.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given that $V=\text{span}(v_1 ,v_2 )$, I used the formula $P=A {(A^T A)}^{-1} A^T$, to find the matrix of orthogonal projection onto V. However I am unsure of how to proceed from here.

Comment: What? I don't understand your formula:
$$P = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T = A (A^{-1} (A^T) ^{-1} ) A^T = (A A^{-1} ) (A^T (A^T)^{-1} ) = I $$
What is this P again? From where is this equation?

Comment: P is the orthogonal projection where P(A) contains vectors which are linearly independent.

Comment: But I showed you that $P=I$ if what you wrote is correct

Comment: Yeah that is strange. Does it have anything to do with (A^T A) being the identity? I just had the equation in my notes, I found a reference of it online. Here you go:http://www.laurentlessard.com/teaching/ece532/cheat_sheet.pdf

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical symbols. I'll edit your question to show how mathjax works.

Comment: OK, now I understand more what you mean. For an  $n\times n$ invert-able matrix, $R(A) = V$ so to project a vector to $R(A)$ means not to change it, so $P$ is $I$. But now I don't understand - what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Once you’ve done all of that inversion and multiplication, you’ve got the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto $V$ relative to the standard basis. What more is there to do? Also, in the future, don’t assume that we can read your mind: explicitly define the variables that you’re using in your question.

Comment: @OfekGillon You’re making some unwarranted assumptions in your initial comment: in particular there’s no reason to believe that $A$ is nonsingular or even square, for that matter.

Comment: You can also compute an orthonormal basis $Q=[q_1,q_2]$ of $V$ (orthogonalize the given basis vectors). Then your orthogonal projection is simply $P=QQ^T$. If that's what the "standard matrix" means.